# Image jumps out of div when viwed on mobile phone Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an image that jumps down and out of its div when I view the website on my phone.. on some phones its okej but not on samsung galaxy note 9 for exemple. I've tried all kinds of things to prevent this from happening and haven't been able to turn the right key. I am using bootstrap 4. I have used media querys but its not working.

[Check the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o8Ei.png)

```
    <section id="showcase" class="">
    <div class="primary-overlay text-white">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
                    <h1 class=" display-2 mt-5 pt-5">Alla företag på ett och samma ställe
                    </h1>
                    <div>



                        <p class="mb-0 lead">För dig som privatkund är Kyndia en app som ger dig tillgång samt
                            information
                            om de företag du har att göra med. Allting i en och samma app.</p>
                        <br>


                        <p><em>Enkelt organiserat och helt gratis.</em></p>


                    </div>


                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">
                        <i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Hämta i Appstore</button>
                    <a href="#news" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Prenumerera </a>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
                    <img src="img/Start.png" alt="" class="img-fluid wow bounceInRight d-sm-block">
                    <!--d-none och d-lg-block-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Max-Width property in CSS.

If you want to extend it to full viewport or container width, use this

```
max-width: 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css

```css
#showcase {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;


}

#showcase h1 {
    font-size: 80px;
}

#showcase .primary-overlay {
    background: #149db9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```